# nvidia and intel low-graphics mode error

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, lightdm

I have ubuntu 14.04.1 64bit installed with intel and nvidia video cards .
I'm using xorg-edgers ppa to graphics drivers .
Today i got an update for the drivers (i think it was the mesa drivers) .
when restarting I got the error in this thread [Error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

I clicked ok and in the next screen i choose : "reconfigure graphics" .
after that rebooting to ubuntu doesn't even reach the lightdm screen and i get black screen with the white coursor in the top left screen , and stays like that .

I tried almost all of the answers in the link above , but didn't help .
More info :
1 - When i choose failsafe x from the recovery menu i get the output :
(EE) fatal server error :
(EE) no screens found
(EE) please contact the xorg foundation .....
after a couple of seconds it returns to the recovey menu .
2 - in one of the answers they talked about /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf file , which i couldn't even find .

What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

after a couple of months with no answers in any "ubuntu" community , i tried to :

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

since after a couple of months there sure would be kernel update and drivers , and it was , 
i just waited for the system to install ~400mb new packages , hoping everything would be ok , 
guess what, it didn't .

**The solution to my problem is** : **wipe** the partition and reinstall ubuntu .
It kindda makes you wonder that an update can break the OS like that , well at least now i understand the blue screen of death for windows .

Comment: What made you switch to "xorg-edgers" ppa instead of the officially supported Nvidia driver? The tested Nvidia drivers should work. ppa-purge of that repo and apt-get upgrade may have fixed it.

Comment: wow this was old , but at the time the drivers in ubuntu ppa were old xorg-edgers had much newer ones .now i'm using ubuntu's ppa cause they  are using new ones on ubuntu 15.04 .